# Problems with freeing memory

Tags: memory-management, managed-c++

I have a form with the following fields:

```
    List<String^>       ^images;
    PictureBox          ^box;.
    List<PictureBox^>   ^boxes;
    String              ^path;
```

(as well as some ints).

I allocate the memory for each of these with `gcnew`, but when I close the form, the memory is not freed. I thought they would be garbage collected; why are they not?

I also noticed an autogenerated `components` variable of type `Container ^` that's `delete`d in the destructor. What's up with that?

EDIT: Whoops, forgot one rather important thing: In the main form from which I call the above forms, I have a List of these forms (to communicate with them). How should I remove the form from the list once it's closed?

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is indeterminate; you can't predict when it will run. All that's guaranteed is that it will run "when it needs to"; if you *absolutely need to control when it happens*, then you can call:

```
GC.Collect();
```

and

```
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: @Markus: Perhaps there's still another reference to your form somewhere -- do you call `Dispose` on it?